# Is clock cycle a length of time?

Tags: computer-science

I'm reading Computer Organization and Design Fifth edition by Patterson and they define clock speed as this:

> Almost all computers are constructed using a clock that determines when events take place in the hardware. These discrete time intervals are called clock cycles (or ticks, clock ticks, clock periods, clocks, cycles). Designers refer to the length of a clock period both as the time for a complete clock cycle (e.g., 250 picoseconds, or 250 ps) and as the clock rate (e.g., 4 gigahertz, or 4 GHz), which is the inverse of the clock period.

What is the difference between clock cycle (some discrete amount of time? and clock period?

My book says the clock period is the length of the clock cycle... but it also says the clock cycle to be the time for one clock period. Isn't this circular?

Comment: Period and Cycle are the same thing. Consider a wave, Period is the amount of time between two peaks on that wave, this is the same time as the clock cycle. I think this question is more suitable for https://physics.stackexchange.com/, as you are looking for definition of time (which is a physics unit)

Answer (score 1):

To address your specific question, a clock cycle is not a measure of time since the clock cycle can vary proportionately with time.  Just like a wavelength, although measured in units of distance is not in itself, a unit of distance.

This is why some very old programs don't work properly even on modern machines that support the instruction set.  They were  using "software timers" that would simply loop for a certain amount of time based on the clock cycle and instruction execution time.  As processors got faster, these programs would simply not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Period is the amount of time betweek clock ticks. For instance, 1 microsecond.

Rate or frequency is the number of clock ticks per unit time. For instance, 1 megahertz.

Frequency = (1 unit time) / Period. 1 megahertz = 1 second / 1 microsecond